# more on reimplementing c++ timerqueue in rust

Tags: rust

continuing this saga [recoding a c++ task queue in rust. Is futures the right abstraction?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63083269/recoding-a-c-task-queue-in-rust-is-futures-the-right-abstraction)

I have worked out how to store the function calls in a vector (I am ignoring all the set, sorting,... stuff for now). Lets just put some requests into a collection and get them run an a different thread.

so I have

```
pub struct TimerQueueItem {
    when: Instant,
    name: String,
    what: QIFunc,
}
type QIFunc = Box<dyn Fn() -> ()>;

struct TimerQueue {
    queue: Vec<TimerQueueItem>,
}
```

I can put these in a vector and then later loop over the vector and call them.

```
let x = || {
    println!("hello");
};
let y = || {
    println!("hello2");
};

let mut tq = TimerQueue::new();
tq.set(Box::new(x), String::from("yo"), Instant::now());
tq.set(Box::new(y), String::from("yo"), Instant::now());

tq.runq();
```

All works fine. But when I try to run the queue on a different thread I get told that I cannot move those QIFunc between threads.

```
fn thr(&mut self)->Sender<i32>{

    let (tx, rx) = channel::<i32>();
    thread::spawn(move ||{
            rx.recv();
            self.runq();
    });
    tx

}
```

gives

```
41  |         thread::spawn(move ||{
    |         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^ `(dyn std::ops::Fn() + 'static)` cannot be sent between threads safely
```

now I could randomly try all sorts of things but I am profoundly trying to get my brain around all this and mapping it to concepts I have from c++. I already feel like I am close to 'magic incantation' land where I cut and paste spells that I dont understand and they seem to work. So pointers to what I should read would be welcome. I have done a lot of reading tho. Just a steep learning curve I guess.

Feels like I am going to need a mutex on the TimerQueue object given thats its shared state between the clients and the worker thread. But that doesnt feel like what is being complained about here

Comment: The concept you need is the send and sync traits, and C++ just doesn't have an equivalent.

Comment: @user1937198 i read about those but dont see what I can do with types that are not mine, I cannot make Box<dyn Fn() -> ()> be send or sync, can I?

Comment: You can, the syntax is `Box<dyn Fn() -> () +Send>` https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/types/trait-object.html

Comment: @user1937198 ty, but this feels like magic. If +Send just says , its OK to move it between threads, what has actually happened? I mean what changed in the type to make it ok. I feel the safety of an operation on a type seems like an intrinsic property of the type, I cant just say I dont agree and actually it is safe for operation x.

Comment: @user1937198 +send traded me that error for another set. I suppose I should post those in another question.