# still trying to reimplement a c++ timerqueue in rust

Tags: rust

[more on reimplementing c++ timerqueue in rust](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63094917/more-on-reimplementing-c-timerqueue-in-rust)

This code tries to create a vec of tasks and run them on a different thread. Still cannot compile it. I am at the point of typing words at random into random locations to see if it helps , 'static here, move there dyn sync ,....

I think if I were to see a working version I would be able to work out why I was stuck. But I cannot make it go.

heres the complete code

```
use std::thread;
use std::time::Instant;

fn main() {
    let x = || {
        println!("hello");
    };
    let y = || {
        println!("hello2");
    };

    let mut tq = TimerQueue::new();
    tq.set(Box::new(x), String::from("yo"), Instant::now());
    tq.set(Box::new(y), String::from("yo"), Instant::now());
    tq.thr();
}

pub struct TimerQueueItem {
    when: Instant,
    name: String,
    what: QIFunc,
}
type QIFunc = Box<dyn Fn() -> () + Send>;

struct TimerQueue {
    queue: Vec<TimerQueueItem>,
}

impl TimerQueue {
    fn thr(&mut self) -> () {
        thread::spawn(move || {
            self.runq();
        });
    }

    fn set(&mut self, f: QIFunc, n: String, when: Instant) {
        let qi = TimerQueueItem {
            what: f,
            name: n,
            when: when,
        };
        self.queue.push(qi);
    }
    fn new() -> TimerQueue {
        TimerQueue { queue: Vec::new() }
    }
    fn runq(&mut self) -> () {
        for qi in self.queue.iter() {
            (qi.what)();
        }
    }
}
```

all sorts of errors all pointing at the same place

```
error[E0495]: cannot infer an appropriate lifetime due to conflicting requirements
  --> src\main.rs:31:23
   |
31 |           thread::spawn(move || {
   |  _______________________^
32 | |             self.runq();
33 | |         });
   | |_________^
   |
note: first, the lifetime cannot outlive the anonymous lifetime #1 defined on the method body at 30:5...
  --> src\main.rs:30:5
```

this one seems particularly designed to confuse

```
   = note: expected `&mut TimerQueue`
              found `&mut TimerQueue`
```

Comment: You cannot move `&mut self` out of the scope, and the compiler is telling you that. The closure outlives the scope that refers to `self` meaning that if rust let you do that you'd experience undefined behavior (referencing freed memory).

Comment: @MeetTitan so what should I do. I want to make a list of closures to be run on a different thread at some point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of `thr(&mut self)`, write `thr(mut self)`.

(`mut` because `runq` wants a mutable reference. It might not need to though.)

You can't transfer ownership of the TimerQueue to the new thread with just a reference. When you "move" something into a closure, you transfer ownership there. On the other hand, if you didn't move (i.e. left the `move` keyword out), you couldn't ensure that `self` would live long enough.

A C++ analogy to this would be

```cpp
// BAD: v may go out of scope in the main
// thread before the new thread completes.
// Also facilitates data races.
std::vector<...> v;
std::thread([&v] () {
  // use/modify v
});

// BETTER: v is moved to be "owned" by the
// closure, so it will certainly live as long as the
// thread is alive.
std::vector<...> v;
std::thread([v=std::move(v)] () mutable {
  // use/modify v
})
```

There's really no such thing as a member function that takes `this` as moved in C++, but there is in Rust. You can think of it as a static class method that looks like this instead:

```cpp
static void thr(TimerQueue &&tq);
// called as
TimerQueue::thr(std::move(tq));
```

Of course, that's not identical to the Rust version in many ways, but hopefully this helps you understand what's going on.

That error message is certainly unhelpful. Not sure what's going on there.

Comment: doesnt compile 'error[E0596]: cannot borrow `self` as mutable, as it is not declared as mutable'

Comment: @pm100 right, `runq` wants a mutable reference (might not need to though). Try `thr(mut self)`.

Comment: hly crp that works. The problem is - I have no idea why. I feel rust is just full of magic incantations that you keep hacking in till it stops complaining.

Comment: It can be cryptic at times but you'll get the hang of it. Through C++ you pretty much already understand what lifetimes are, they just exist on a semantic level that's not written in code. That and knowing the basics of Rust's ownership and references should take you pretty far. Did you grasp my C++ analogy?

Comment: ty, please update the answer to reflect what actually worked and I will mark it as the answer. I am really close to giving up entirely. Go back go - which I love

Comment: Done. I made the C++ lambdas `mutable` as well to be symmetric.

Comment: if you had waited a day you would of got a bounty :-)

Comment: Shoot, I already waited a day since I thought someone more knowledgeable would respond. :)

Answer (score 1):

Your TimerQueue object is stored on the stack of the main thread. Because Rust cannot guarantee that the new thread will finish before the main one, it has imposed some restrictions on how you can pull off recreating your timerqueue.

I actually found a simple fix. Basically, I removed the *thr* method and moved its body into main.

```
use std::thread;
use std::time::Instant;

fn main() {
    let x = || {
        println!("hello");
    };
    let y = || {
        println!("hello2");
    };

    let mut tq = TimerQueue::new();
    tq.set(Box::new(x), String::from("yo"), Instant::now());
    tq.set(Box::new(y), String::from("yo"), Instant::now());

    thread::spawn(move || {
        tq.runq();
    });

    thread::sleep_ms(1000);
}

pub struct TimerQueueItem {
    when: Instant,
    name: String,
    what: QIFunc,
}
type QIFunc = Box<dyn Fn() -> () + Send>;

struct TimerQueue {
    queue: Vec<TimerQueueItem>,
}

impl TimerQueue {

    fn set(&mut self, f: QIFunc, n: String, when: Instant) {
        let qi = TimerQueueItem {
            what: f,
            name: n,
            when: when,
        };
        self.queue.push(qi);
    }

    fn new() -> TimerQueue {
        TimerQueue { queue: Vec::new() }
    }

    fn runq(&mut self) -> () {
        for qi in self.queue.iter() {
            (qi.what)();
        }
    }
}
```

Note: I added the

```
thread::sleep_ms(1000);
```

which ensures that the main thread will last as long as the spawned thread - at least in this example, other scenarios might have the new thread require more time. If you want to pause the main thread until the spawned one completes (regardless of how long the spawned one takes), you can replace

```
thread::spawn(move || {
    tq.runq();
});

thread::sleep_ms(1000);
```

with

```
let thread_handle = thread::spawn(move || {
    tq.runq();
});

thread_handle.join();
```

For reference, my *cargo* version is 1.41.0

Comment: well ty for the input but. In your fixed version the tq object is still local to the main func stack and so I dont see how that resolves it if thats what the issue was. Also the caller now has to know the internals of the tq object, that have to start a thread etc. I fundamentally dont see the difference between my code and yours. I mean I see what you changed but why did that make a difference and I still not the original code (ie encapsulated internals) to work

Comment: I'm not 100% sure why my version works but I do have a theory. Know that once main ends, the *tq* object would go out of scope and this would be dangerous if the spawned thread using it was still active. My theory is that by placing the spawn code in main, the compiler could ensure that the thread is terminated before that object goes out of scope (and main ends) whereas the compiler can't ensure that if the spawn call was in that object's method.

Comment: Thats what I am discovering about rust. I am v experienced c++ dev (since Zorland c++) and thought I would use rust for my next project. Seems like its full of voodoo magic spells that nobody can really explain. Thats kind of disconcerting